# Django input login for an admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

How can I add attribute `autocomplete="off"` to the input login template form for an admin?

I'm find this in the `login.html` template but can't find where is the form template

```
<div class="form-row">
    {{ form.username.errors }}
    {{ form.username.label_tag }} {{ form.username }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change behavior based on whether or not the user is admin/staff:

```
{% if request.user.is_staff %}
    <form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="action_name">
        <input autocomplete="off" name="hidden" type="text" style="display:none;">
{% else %}
    <form method="post" action="action_name">
{% endif %}
    <div class="form-row">
```

And complete the rest of the form as you would.
Reference for the form and input tags to turn autocomplete off (note autocomplete is "off" in the input tag as per testing in comments): 
https://gist.github.com/niksumeiko/360164708c3b326bd1c8